# creating a "floating" html node in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have used jQuery quite often for ajax calls as follows (and this is "abbreviated"):

```
$('#some_element').load(some_url);
```

That puts the object in the DOM immediately.

However, what I want to do is build a new node, do operations on it first (specifically) changing the title and adding HTML in regions within it, and then append the modified HTML to #some_element. This is new to me.

So for example suppose the data that would come back would be as follows:

```
<div id="title"></div>
<div id="body"></div>
```

I want to load that data by ajax, then add content to the title div, perhaps set classes for the elements or even bind behaviors, and THEN append it into an element.  Can you show me an example?  Thanks; the problem is that at my level of newness here I'm not sure of the terms to ask/search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the callback to `$.load()`, you can modify the DOM elements there:

```
$("#some_element").load(some_url, function() {
    $("#title").html(whatever);
});
```

The callback will run after the elements are added to the DOM, but I don't think that should make a difference. Nothing will be rendered until after the callback finishes, so it doesn't matter whether you make the changes before or after they're added.

Comment: the key statement here seems to be "nothing will be rendered until the callback finishes".  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at the jQuery get method, to fetch the result of a url

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

It'll look something like this:

```
$.get(
  'www.example.com/this',
  function(response,status) {
    alert(status);
    $.html(response);
  }
  'html'
);
```

Comment: OK, so two points: 1. http://api.jquery.com/html/ says that html() accepts no arguments, but the big question 2. if the html returned is a variable, how will I manipulate it?  It's not an object - so I can't do $("#title").html('Modified before placing')

Comment: There's two modes of usage for .html, the second is .html( htmlString ). The html returned will be a string, in my example it's named response.